# "He was playing when he fell" or "he fell when he was playing"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, relative-clauses, phrase-order

Which one is correct?

> He fell down when he was playing in the field.
>   He was playing in the field when he fell down.

Why?

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct; you would choose according to context.

The first suggests that the fall is the topic (i.e. you are explaining the circumstances of a fall, for example to a doctor) while the second suggests his play is the topic (you are describing his play in the field, and mention the fall as the next event in a sequence.)

The ambiguity of the sentence structure arises because "when" has slightly different meanings in the two contexts. In the first sentence, you use "when" to introduce the answer to a potential question:

*When did he fall down?*

*He fell down* when *he was playing in the field.*

In the second sentence, the word "when" is actually used in place of the now-uncommon "whereupon," meaning "at which time":

*He was playing in the field,* whereupon *he fell down.*

In speech however, the second sentence could convey the same meaning as the first, provided emphasis is place on the first clause, especially the gerund and noun *playing* and *field*. In this case the sentence-reversal is used to emphasise the circumstance of the fall by bringing it to the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: -1: I don't see how there is any difference in meaning.

Comment: -1: to my ear too there is a slight difference in meaning/emphasis, but the difference for me doesn’t fit your description at all; and the “when” in the second form surely means “while” (as per Gurzo’s answer) not “whereupon”?  I wouldn’t have even considered interpreting it as a sequential description.

Answer (score 6):

Grammatically, both are equally correct, but stylistically, the second construction can be used for greater effect. For example:

> - I was walking down the street with my mom when she got hit by a truck.
> - He was playing piano when he dropped dead.

Compare that with:

> - My mom got hit by a truck when we were walking down the street.
> - He dropped dead when he was playing piano.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't:

```
He fell down WHILE he was playing in the field.
```

and

```
He was playing in the field when he fell down.
```

be both correct and viable?

Comment: I was also expecting a while in the first sentence.